# Call a private method using a String in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, methods

ok I do have class like this.

```
Namespace mySpace

 Public Class ClassA

     Private Function MethodA(prm AS Boolean) As Boolean
       Return False
     End Function

     Private Function MethodB() As Boolean
       Return False
     End Function

 End Class

 Public Class ClassB

     Private Function MethodC() As Boolean
       Return True
     End Function

     Private Function InvokeA() As Boolean
        Dim methodObj As MethodInfo
        'null pointer except below here
        methodObj = Type.GetType("mySpace.ClassA").GetMethod("MethodA") 
        Dim params As Boolean() = {False}
        Return CBool(methodObj.Invoke(New ClassA(), params)) 
     End Function

 End Class

End Namespace
```

What I am trying here is to invoke a method from a different class with parameters using its method. But this returns a null pointer exception. Why? Where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing various things wrong. The following code should work without any problem:

```
Dim objA As ClassA = New ClassA()
methodObj = objA.GetType().GetMethod("MethodA", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
Dim params As Object() = {False}
methodObj.Invoke(objA, params)
```

You have various errors which shouldn't allow your code to run at all, namely:

- You are retrieving a private method without the adequate
  `BindingFlags`.
- You are not passing the arguments as `Object` type.

Additionally, you are not using `GetMethod` with an instantiated object of `ClassA` (e.g., `objA` above) and `instance.GetType()`; I am not 100% sure that you need to do that (perhaps you can accomplish it as you intend), but performing this step is a pretty quick process and would allow the code above to work without any problem.

Comment: -1 for suggesting to create a new instance to get the type of an instance if the type is already well known (why not just `GetType(ClassA)`?). Also, you're using the wrong `BindingFlags`, too. It should be `BindingFlags.Instance` instead of `BindingFlags.CreateInstance `

Comment: @DominicKexel the bindingFlag was a typo. And I haven't suggested to instantiate a new ClassA, I have said that I wasn't sure. Could you please write a code as you suggest?

Comment: @DominicKexel instead critising, you should contribute towards solving the problems, don't you think (haven't either see your solution in the other critic you made). I look forward to your solution.

Comment: `Type.GetType("mySpace.ClassA")` works fine, or you could just use `GetType(ClassA)` to get the `Type` (as I said in my comment).

Comment: @DominicKexel I am trying it and it does not work. Could you please, write a code confim that it works as you suggest, otherwise remove your -1?

Comment: @DominicKexel because do you agree with my other statements don't you? I am really sorry about the typo (although I would just let the answerer know via friendly comment, intead of UNFAIR -1)

Comment: OK, I removed my downvote since your code works now and you solved two problems of the OP's code (missing BindingFlags, wrong type of the array). But creating a new instance of `ClassA` just to call `GetType()` on that instance is still terrible, because you can just use the `GetType`-operator.

Comment: Also, *you are not using GetMethod with an instance of the class* makes no sense, since the `GetMethod` method is an instance method of the type `Type`.

Comment: @DominicKexel thanks. I do agree with you on that instantiating a new ClassA sounds horrible; but if I don't do that the code does not work (by doing Type.GetType("mySpace.ClassA")). I have done some quick research to look for explanations and didn't find anything. If any answerer writes a code working without instantiating I will delete this answer right away.

Comment: @DominicKexel I think that "you are not using GetMethod with an instance of the class" is self-explanatory. Instead of using GetMethod directly with ClassA, I am using it with an instance of it, objA. I am open to any suggestion regarding how to write this idea better.

Comment: You're calling the `GetMethod` method on an instance of the `Type` class. It does not matter if you got this instance by using the `GetType`-method or the `GetType`-operator. It's the same instance.

Comment: @DominicKexel OK. I have edited my answer to transmit these ideas better.